# Formal definition of the Differential of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, infinitesimals

The formal definition of the differential of a differentiable function $f: x \mapsto y=f(x)$ is that it's a two-variable function, its name is $df$ and its value is $df(x,\Delta_X) = f'(x)\cdot\Delta_X$.

It's used by Courant for instance and i read in Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#CITEREFCourant1937i )  that it's the modern treatise of differentials in differential calculus .

I'm trying to see how do we go from that to $df(x) = f'(x) dx$  and then if $y=f(x)$, to the usual $dy = f '(x) dx$ that we see everywhere regarding linear approximation.

First of all, what would $dx$ mean ? Is it the differential of what function ? What about $dy$ or $df(x)$, is it the differential of what function ?   What would be the values of those differentials ?

Since the formal definition of differentials treats it like a function i can't understand what these symbols "$dx$" and "$dy$" actually mean in the usual context.
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: on it's vs. its: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe not a big deal, just putting it out there.

Comment: $dx$ would simply be the differential for $f(x)=x$, which would just give you $\Delta_X$.  Remember that differentials are generally very small.  The "meaningful" (i.e. measurable and observable) thing to look at is the ratio $dy/dx$

Comment: Another way to think of the differentials $dy$ and $dx$ is to take them as the respective top and bottom of the difference quotient, $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ In order to approximate the slope of the tangent line at a point (i.e. the derivative), we find the slope of secant lines with progressively closer intersections (i.e. average rates of change or linearizations at the point) by reducing $h$.  That is, the smaller our $dy$ and $dx$, the better $dy/dx$ approximates the derivative.

Comment: I get your point about dx but i still dont understand what "dy" would mean, would that be the differential of what function ?

Comment: Well that's precisely what you answered in the beginning of your question: $dy$, given the relationship $y=f(x)$, is the differential of your function $f(x)$.  $df$ and $dy$, assuming we're talking about a situation in which $y$ is dependent on $x$ in that way, are the same thing.

Comment: Since df and dy are actually names of functions, how can we relate them with the value dx of the differential of f(x) = f ? Wouldn't we need to relate the values ( instead of the name ) of those functions with dx? Wouldn't we need something like df(x,deltaX) = f'(x)dx ? I'm really confused, been thinking about this for 5 hours;.

Comment: Hey nerd, it's just a *notation*!

Comment: Now what's the difference between your $df(x,\Delta_x)=f'(x)dx$ and $df(x,\Delta_x)=f'(x)\Delta_x$?  Remember: $dx$ and $\Delta_x$ are the same thing!  We could have also written (and I don't see why they don't write this) $df(x,dx)=f'(x)\cdot dx$

Comment: Here's the real issue, I think: the theory of differentials doesn't show why $df(x,dx)=f'(x) dx$.  It assumes it, and figures things out from there.  This fact itself comes from the definition of continuity, applied to a derivative.

Comment: I know, i see no difference between  df(x,Δx)=f′(x)dx and df(x,Δx)=f′(x)Δx . What i see is a big difference between df(x,Δx) and df or dy.

Comment: For example, since df=dy is the name ( not the value ) of function we couldnt possibly equate it to some real value. That would be the same as defining f : x -> f(x)  then doing a statement f = 3

Comment: Well, we don't do that.  Just because we don't write out the parentheses every time, doesn't mean that $df$ loses its dependence on $dx$.  In order to know what $df$ is, we need to know what both $x$ and $dx$ are.  That is consistently true.

Comment: What Courant wrote is correct. What you find in calculus books that confuses a finite change in $x$ and $dx$ and the same for $y$ is both incorrect and the author of this confusion.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Omnomnomonomom.I'm almost getting it.I understood the dx is the value of the differential of f(x)=x .You are suggesting that when i see dy = f'(x)dx i treat dy like  df(x,dx) since dx = deltaX ?

Comment: Yes.  Also, sorry my username takes up so many characters; I should have thought that through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, $x:M\to\mathbb R$ is a map from a manifold $M$ into the reals.

For one dimensional calculus, the manifold $M$ is usually taken to be $\mathbb R$ or a region thereof. $x(p)$ is a function used as a coordinate, and it tells you where on the manifold you are. Its argument is the abstract point on the manifold. Therefore, the manifold is the set of all possible points you might be sitting at. You usually think of just one point at a time.

$y=f(x)$ is also a function on the manifold, and by the chain rule $\mathrm d y|_p= f'(x(p)) \mathrm d x|_p$ at $p$, a point on the manifold.

You could also view $y$ as a local coordinate and then $x=x(y)$ locally and so on.

---

A vector field $X^a$ on a manifold $M$ is a map from functions $f$ to their rate of change along that vector $X(f)=X^a\partial_a f$ in any coords. In one dimension, a vector field has one component so we can write it as $X$. In fact, we can interpret their action for small values $\Delta (f) = f' \times \Delta$ as being a predictor of the results of a small change in position (the flow along the integral curves of $\Delta$.

A differential of a function $\mathrm d f$ is a **map from vector fields to functions** given by $\mathrm d f(\Delta) \equiv \Delta (f)$. That is,

> differentials of functions are maps from vector fields to the derivative/small change along that vector field of the function **or** maps from vector fields/small changes and points to real numbers, which give the small change in that function at that point induced by following the vector field away from that point

Therefore $\mathrm d x$ just stores the information about how fast the coordinate $x$ changes. You make arguments like this:
$$(\mathrm d f(x))(\Delta)(p)=\Delta(f(x(p)))= \Delta^a(p)\partial_a f(x(p)) = \Delta^a(p) \partial_a x(p)\times f'(x(p)) = f'(x(p)) \Delta (x(p)) = f'(x(p)) (\mathrm d x)(\Delta)(p)$$
and by linearity comparing the left and right we deduce
$$\mathrm d f = f'(x) \mathrm d x$$

You can figure out a 'small change' interpretation of all this because the definition of a vector field is exactly what it needs to be for this to work.

*Note*: By $\partial_a$ I mean a derivative with respect to the $a$th coordinate which is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i still don't see how you treat differentials. How do you see the differential of a function and how do you see dy and dx ?

Comment: What does "see" mean?

Comment: I meant : How do you mentally represent the idea behind the strings "dx" or "dy", used by many mathematicians and included in many books ? Do you identify them as a function ? Then what  function ? Do you identify them like numbers ?

Comment: I've expanded on the correct formal definitions from differential geometry; does this help? I should emphasize that the **informal intuition** is similar but slightly simpler - one imagines $\mathrm d x$ as representing a very small number, and $\mathrm d f(x)$ as being another small number proportional to the above change in $x$ telling you how this function changes. This fits in by with the formal definition by taking $\Delta$ small and evaluating at only the point $p$ corresponding to the $x$ you started at.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i know nothing about differential geometry and very little about multi-variable calculus.I'm a bit confused with your answer, i was trying to keep it simple by only using functions and derivatives.I'm sure this was a pretty good answer and i'm gonna review it when i start studying about multi-variable calculus.

Comment: Sorry, it's never easy to guess the right level in advance. You can forget allthe vector field and partial derivative stuff in 1D and think of $\Delta$ as a function telling you how much to move at every point; this includes how to shift any coordinate at each point. The differential takes that shift and tells you the change in the function it's the differential of.

Answer (score 1):

Since Newton and Leibniz, several approaches appeared to target this question.

Let me mention one of them:

One can realize real *infinitesimals*, as  real sequences $(d_1,d_2,d_3,\dots)$ which tend to $0$. Two sequences represent the same 'number' if they differ only in finite coordinates. Moreover, any first order formula is true if it is true except for finite places. (Actually, we take an ultrapower $^*{\Bbb R}:=\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}/{\mathcal U}$ with some nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\Bbb N$.) The original real numbers are embedded in ${}^*{\Bbb R}$ as the *constant* sequences.
 
The important consequence is, there are *infinitesimals* in ${}^*\Bbb R$, for example
$$\delta:=(1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\dots)$$
which is bigger than $0$, as it holds for all coordinates, and it is smaller than $\frac1n$ for all $n$ because that fails only in finitely many coordinates.

Let $a\simeq b$ mean that $b-a$ is infinitesimal (i.e. $b-a\in (-1/n,1/n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$).

In this setting, we can fix any infinitesimal, and call it $dx$. If a function $f:\Bbb R\,\to\Bbb R$ is given, it extends to ${}^*\Bbb R$, by applying it in each coordinates. Then we have that $f$ is differentiable in point $x$ with derivative $f'(x)$ iff $\displaystyle\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}\simeq f'(x)$ for *any* infinitesimal $dx$. 
(So, if we already know that $f$ is differentiable, then we have to check only for one $dx$.)

Now, as $dx$ is considered fixed, the other ones can be given as
 $$dy:=df(x)=f(x+dx)-f(x)\,.$$
Then we indeed have $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}\simeq f'(x)$, as well as $dy\simeq f'(x)\cdot dx$. And everything gets in place.

An important point is, that sometimes it is useful to change and take another infinitesimal as the base one, say $dy$, and express everything by that...

Comment: Thanks for your point about real infinitesimals but i was trying to see how the definition of differentials of functions as functions could explain dy = f'(x)dx

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally misunderstood your question:) I think, you can apply it with $\Delta_X$ any infinitesimal (that was called $dx$ above).

Answer (score 0):

Differentials are a case where the common formal definition found in elementary calculus courses has little to do with the original meaning of the concept.

The original meaning of the concept, is an infinitesimal (infinitely small) change in something.  $\Delta x$ is a finite change in $x$, but $dx$ is an infinitesimal change in $x$. So $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ can be used as the slope of a line, but for the analogous concept for functions in general (the derivative), we need to take $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ so small that that the segment of the function they delimit is a line segment.  Of course, for a lot of functions, that segment won't be a line segment however small $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are made, so they must be made infinitely small, and the derivative is expressed $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

This was the original meaning of differentials conceived by Leibniz, and it is still used all the time in applied math.  The derivative rules are very easily, though non-rigorously, derived with this "definition" (see Thompson's "Calculus Made Easy").

The definition $dy=y'(x)dx$ is a modern definition designed to retroactively justify Leibniz' notation.  $dx$ is just any finite real number, for this system, so now we're allowed to say $y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$.  But as you can see, $dy$ and $dx$ really aren't infinitesimals anymore, they are just $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ for the tangent line approximation. It still works formally, but now $y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$ seems very circular.

There are formal ways of expressing differentials that retain their original meaning as well, but they are more complicated. These ways are described in some of the other answers.